# Attribute asset to minimize variance in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I have an optimization problem to solve. Here is the context : I have potential "screens" that I can buy to broadcast an ad. Each screen has a value called "grp". The thing is, I have different films, and what I'm trying to do is to minimize the variance in total grp for each film.

I have one constraint : all screens must be attributed to a film.

Here is an example of list of available screens :

```
    date     channel    screen_id format grp
    <dttm>     <chr>        <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 2017-10-08 channel A      2142 *  45s  9.95
2 2017-10-08 channel A      2391 T  30s  1.43
3 2017-10-09 channel A      2320 S  20s  2.60
4 2017-10-09 channel A      2410 S  20s  1.03
5 2017-10-09 channel A      2430 S  20s  0.78
6 2017-10-10 channel A      1903 S  20s  2.70
```

I have three different films, let's call them `c("film_A", "film_B", "film_C")` and I want to make sure to minimize the difference of total grp per film.

Expected output (here the attribution is random, therefor not optimized) :

```
        date   channel screen_id format   grp   film
      <dttm>     <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <dbl>  <chr>
1 2017-10-08 channel A      2142 *  45s  9.95 film_a
2 2017-10-08 channel A      2391 T  30s  1.43 film_b
3 2017-10-09 channel A      2320 S  20s  2.60 film_c
4 2017-10-09 channel A      2410 S  20s  1.03 film_a
5 2017-10-09 channel A      2430 S  20s  0.78 film_b
6 2017-10-10 channel A      1903 S  20s  2.70 film_c
```

In this case the total grp per film has a high variance :

```
    film grp_per_film
   <chr>        <dbl>
1 film_a        16.45
2 film_b         3.78
3 film_c         6.50
```

What I'm trying to minimize is the variance of the total grp by film, and not the variance of grp by screen in each film as a group.

I'm a bit stuck on this one. I've looked into the PortfoliAnalytics package, but I can't apply the portfolio logic to this problem.

Comment: What is the desired result of your example input?

Comment: Hey, thanks, I've updated the question.

Comment: The desired result doesn't fit your criteria. film_a is in grp 9.95 and 1.03. The difference between those 2 is not minimized.

Comment: The output in the example is random, and what I'm trying to minimize is the difference between the sum of grp for each film. So in this case I have 16.45 grp for film a, 3.78 for film b and 6.5 for film c. The variance is huge between the movies indeed, that's what I'm trying to minimize.

Comment: Before writing code I would recommend to develop a mathematical model first. Think about the objective (minimize variance), your constraints (budget constraint, target grp) and decision variables (what to buy). Just minimizing variance would yield an optimal solution of not buying anything.

Comment: That's a really good point, I wasn't explicit enough in my original question. I'll edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do using `kmeans`. Basically, `kmeans` creates 3 grp clusters. This will indeed minimize the difference in grps between clusters.

```
dt <- read.table(text="
date       channel       screen_id format grp
2017-10-08 'channel A'      '2142 '  45s  9.95
2017-10-08 'channel A'     '2391 T'  30s  1.43
2017-10-09 'channel A'      '2320 S'  20s  2.60
2017-10-09 'channel A'      '2410 S'  20s  1.03
2017-10-09 'channel A'      '2430 S'  20s  0.78
2017-10-10 'channel A'      '1903 S'  20s  2.702",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dt$film <- kmeans(dt$grp,centers=3)$cluster

        date   channel screen_id format   grp film
1 2017-10-08 channel A     2142     45s 9.950    2
2 2017-10-08 channel A    2391 T    30s 1.430    1
3 2017-10-09 channel A    2320 S    20s 2.600    3
4 2017-10-09 channel A    2410 S    20s 1.030    1
5 2017-10-09 channel A    2430 S    20s 0.780    1
6 2017-10-10 channel A    1903 S    20s 2.702    3
```

If you wanted to use `data.table` (could be useful to group by date or week), this would work:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[,film:=kmeans(grp,centers=3)$cluster]

         date   channel screen_id format   grp film
1: 2017-10-08 channel A     2142     45s 9.950    2
2: 2017-10-08 channel A    2391 T    30s 1.430    1
3: 2017-10-09 channel A    2320 S    20s 2.600    3
4: 2017-10-09 channel A    2410 S    20s 1.030    1
5: 2017-10-09 channel A    2430 S    20s 0.780    1
6: 2017-10-10 channel A    1903 S    20s 2.702    3
```

Comment: That's a really elegant way to limit the variance of grp within all the screens attributed for each film. But what I want to minimize is the difference of the sum of grp between each film. I'll edit my question.